# How to use useState in React 15 with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I want to use react-bootstrap's Collapse in a project, but it requires useState from react-hooks, which has been introduced in react version 16.8. However, the project is still on react version 15.3 and updating is not an option.

Can someone suggest how to implement this react-bootstrap example using react 15.3?

```
  function Example() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
      <>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
          aria-expanded={open}
        >
          click
        </Button>
        <Collapse in={open}>
          <div id="example-collapse-text">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
            terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
            labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </div>
        </Collapse>
      </>
    );
  }

  render(<Example />);
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-react-bootstrap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.8",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "typescript": "3.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Make it a regular class based component and call setState

Comment: The answer to `How to use useState in React 15` is **You don't**. It isn't supported, so either upgrade your version of react or dont use hooks. If you want to create this same example in v15 then just create a regular class with state.

Answer (score 4):

It's not mandatory that you use hooks for this reactstrap example. You can create a class-based component and still accomplish the same feature.

```
import { Button, Collapse } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: true
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState( (prevState: { open: any; }) => ({
      open: !prevState.open
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const {open} = this.state
    console.log(open);
    return (
      <div>
      <Button
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
          aria-expanded={open}
        >
          click
        </Button>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout={0}>
          <div id="example-collapse-text">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
            terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
            labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </div>
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Also, make sure to import the react-strap stylesheet and scripts to your public/index.html file. Put these in the `head` tag

```
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    />

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    />

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
      crossorigin
    />

    <script>
      var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
    </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: @JohnRuddell that's hilarious lol. Also, explains why I've been able to get more marked answers, since you're leaving them open for me haha.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but let's tone down the ribbing please. Back the problem at hand, I can't get the above solution to work under react 15.0.8.

Comment: Christopher Ngo, I've modified your answer so that it compiles, but the Collapse does not open/close. Can you give me a working version or explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm waiting for my edits to be peer-reviewed, so sorry if my comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dfdumaresq you probably still need to add the stylesheet and scripts that are required to use react-strap see: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/   Put those items in your publc/index.html file Also here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-framework-gd73l which you can refer to

Comment: Thanks for that, Christopher! Mine briefly shows the text, but then the container collapses. I see the same thing in your sandbox, when I downgrade react-bootstrap to "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4".
When I try to run with "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.12" it causes breaking changes.
I will upload my package.json. I see you're using react 16, but this might work just be fixing the Transistion in react-bootstrap.

Comment: @dfdumaresq hmm thats so strange, I dont actually see the bug you've mentioned :(. You're right, it might just be compatibility issues with the package versions. Have you had any luck resolving this? Or I might just be misinterpreting the bug haha. Do you just want the text to be hidden on click, (no transition).

Comment: Yeah - I just want it to be hidden on click. No transition.

Comment: @dfdumaresq you can just give the Collapse component a timeout prop as noted in the documentation.         `<Collapse in={open} timeout={0}>` that will make it so theres no transition. See updated code above and sandbox for reference.

Comment: Christopher, using a timeout on the Collapse component does not seem to work with `react-bootstrap: 0.32.4`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the current [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js) by react.

However, i wouldn't recommend recreating it. So here are the real options:

- First it might be a good idea to challenge the reasons for not upgrading if you want to start using hooks. (many people don't challenge this, but i'd say the best option would always be to upgrade. It resolves security issues and prevents you from having to reinvent the wheel.
- That said; if it's really not an option to upgrade, you may refer to the official documentation for [react: state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class). It will mean that you have to convert your components into classes every time you need state in your component. You may refer to the answer from @ChristopherNgo for what your implementation would look like.
- For specific cases you may use redux, to make the state globally available to your app. In your example case it may make little sense however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Webber. We _are_ challenging the reasons for not upgrading, but have a lot of dependencies that need to be dealt with.
A collapsing container is the important part of this and I may need to look at something other than Boostrap that just works in v15.